# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "page". Expected Number with value 0, got String with value ""

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I am doing a filter and reset button in the website . However, whenever i press the reset button , it keep shows that `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "page". Expected Number with value 0, got String with value "".` I couldn't find the root problem as I did not define any prop "page". Can anyone help me with this

`index.vue`

```
            <v-data-table
                :headers="tableHeaders"
                :items="tableData.results"
                :options.sync="tableOptions"
                :sort-desc.sync="tableSortDesc"
                :sort-by.sync="tableSortBy"
                :server-items-length="tableData.count"
                class="elevation-1 pt-xs-3 pt-sm-3"
                :items-per-page="5"
                v-model="selectedTableData"
                show-select
                :loading="isTableLoading"
                :page="itemPageNumber"
            >
 computed: {
     itemPageNumber() {
       if (this.filters.hasOwnProperty('page')) {
         return this.filters.page.value
       }

       return 1
     }
  },
```

`Console error message`

```
found in

---> <VDataTable>
       <VCard>
         <BaseData> at components/BaseData.vue
           <BaseListing> at components/BaseListing.vue
             <MedicalAdminClinicIndex> at pages/medical/activity/index.vue
               <Nuxt>
                 <VMain>
                   <VApp>
                     <DefaultLayout> at layouts/default.vue
                       <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
    VueJS 23
    created SnackBar.vue:29
    commit vuex.common.js:474
    commit vuex.common.js:472
    boundCommit vuex.common.js:411
    showSnackBar notifier.js:12
    _callee4$ index.vue:564
    Babel 10
    resetFilter mixin-medical-global-index.js:41
    VueJS 4
    reset BaseFilter.vue:16
    VueJS 4
    click vuetify.js:2609
    VueJS 33
```

Comment: Can you add the minimal code to showcase your issue?

Comment: i just added the code , but i am not sure whether its this part of code is showing the errors

Comment: i think i found the problem. `:page="itemPageNumber"` when i remove this line , the error would be removed. however i still need this. is there any way to solve this

Comment: @Salvino could u help me look into it ? i just updated the code that showcase my issue

Comment: Are you sure the type of this.filters.page.value is number. Does it have "" at any case?

Comment: try this:
if (this.filters.hasOwnProperty('page') && this.filters.page != '') {
    return this.filters.page.value
}

Comment: still the same. when i console log `this.filters.page.value` , it return an empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `props - :page` you are passing in the `VDataTable` has the matching type (in your case it should be `Number`.

The root problem is you have defined the type as `Number` for the prop value but somehow a `String` is being passed, eventually throwing the error.

```
computed: {
  itemPageNumber() {
    if (this.filters.hasOwnProperty('page') && this.filters.page !== "") {
      return Number(this.filters.page.value)   
      //use Number function only if page.value has String type
    }

    return 1
  }
},
```